# how to drop Temporal Tables in SQLite which were created with a CSV file that is not longer available?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to drop a temp table that was created with a csv file which is not longer available. I am using SQLPro on Mac.

```
drop table mytemptable;
```

[image: my error]

Comment: Temporary tables will be dropped when the database is closed.

Comment: Even closing it, the table is persistan when open the database.

Comment: I think it has to deal with the fact of which software you created the table with. In my example, I used SQLPro Studio.

Comment: Most likely a [*virtual* table](https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html).

Answer (score 0):

After some deep search, here is the code:

PRAGMA writable_schema = ON;

DELETE FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'NameOfTheTable';

Comment: Manually modifying `sqlite_master` does not drop the actual table and risks database corruption.

Comment: Taking in consideration, but for me worked for those temporal tables that don't find the the path of the civ files(the source).

Comment: Add the Code ``` symbols around your code